# Generating an asymmetrical grid of 3 divs

Tags: css

I would like to create a simple css layout with three cells, where each cell contains one div. I would like these cells to resize to conform to the shape of the browser window when it is resized. I'd like the layout that I'm describing to look roughly like this, where each rectangle is one of the 3 cells:

```
#############################################
#                                     #     #
#######################################     #
#                                     #     #
#                                     #     #
#                                     #     #
#                                     #     #
#                                     #     #
#                                     #     #
#                                     #     #
#############################################
```

I can get something that approximately correct, however I can't figure out how to get the windows to format correctly when I resize the browser window. How can I create this CSS?

Comment: Try using percentage width

Comment: Could you post the HTML and CSS you’re using now (possibly as a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))? It would be a lot easier to help you that way.